# Why wont $(this).children() work for me?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

EDITED*** Thank you for the help below. I understand $(this).children() now and I have it working... somewhat. I need some help to get it 100%.

I have a list of icons and upon clicking, I have it set up to open a tooltip and dropdown menu beneath the respective icon.

All the icons have the same class. All the dropdowns look the same (and have the same class) and I am using one class in the jQuery code for the tooltip and dropdown.

I see now that by using .children() that it will pull the direct child first. It is working with .hover() to show the tooltip. However, for the other effects (widening tooltip, sliding dropdown, you can see in the code), nothing happens upon .click(). I added $(this).children() consistently so not sure why it works in one place but not another. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for the help thus far as well.

Now for the code... 
(forgive me for the indentation not being great, I'm not sure if I'm the only one who experiences problems copy/pasting things into here, but it always gets screwed up. I have fixed it some, but not 100%)

HTML:

```
<div class="topIcon">

    <a href="stream.html"><img src="icons/stream16lg.png" /></a>
    <div class="topIconNew"></div>
    <div class="topTip">
        <div class="topTipText">Stream</div>
    </div>
    <div class="topDrop">What's up</div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var clicked = false;

// tooltip hover

$("div.topIconNew, div.topIcon, div#topSend, div#topTool").hover(
function(){$(this).children("div.topTip").show();},
function(){
    if(!clicked) {
        $(this).children("div.topTip").hide();
        $(this).children('div.topTip').hide();
    }
}
);        

//tooltip widening and dropdown menu

$("div.topIconNew").click(function(){

    //permanent tooltip
    $(this).children("div.topTip").show();  
    $(this).children("div.topTip").animate({width:320,marginLeft:-240},"fast");
    $(this).children("div.topDrop").slideDown(240);
    clicked = true;
});
    $("div.wrapper").click(function(){

    //hide dropdown (hide simultaneously)

    $(this).children("div.topDrop, div.topTip").hide();
});

});
```

Comment: I've updated my answer below to work with the code you posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.imageClass').click(function() {
    var whatYoureLookingFor = $(this).next('.dropDownTooltipClass');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a guess

```
 $('.someClass').click(function(){
    $(this).children(); // to access a dom under the clicked item
    $(this).next();     // to access is direct next dom
 });
```

So you are only working with the clicked element

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly. I would have it be $(this).children("children I want selected");?

Comment: You would use either the `.childre()` or `.next()` in both of them you can add a selector if needed. It depends on your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Answer revised to fit the markup you posted.

Your code is not working because `.topTip` is not a child of `.topIconNew`.  You first need to use the technique described in my original answer below – find the parent and then its children. Use `$(this).closest(".topIcon")` to find the parent.  `.closest()` returns the current element if it matches the selector, or the first ancestor that matches the selector.

```
$("div.topIconNew, div.topIcon, div#topSend, div#topTool").hover(
    function () { $(this).closest(".topIcon").children("div.topTip").show(); },
    function () {
        if(!clicked) {
            $(this).closest(".topIcon").children("div.topTip").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

You'll find another issue though.  Since the variable `clicked` is shared, once an icon is clicked, all of the tooltips will remain visible after hovering for all of the icons.  You need to make `clicked` local to the individual icons.  The easiest way to accomplish that would probably be to store `clicked` in the `.data()` for each `.topIcon`:

```
$("div.topIconNew, div.topIcon, div#topSend, div#topTool").hover(
    function() { $(this).closest(".topIcon").children("div.topTip").show(); },
    function() {
        var icon = $(this).closest(".topIcon");
        if(!icon.data("clicked")) {
            icon.children("div.topTip").hide();
        }
    }
});
$("div.topIconNew").click(function () {
    //permanent tooltip
    var icon = $(this).parent();
    icon.children("div.topTip")
        .show()
        .animate({ width: 320, marginLeft: -240 }, "fast");
    icon.children("div.topDrop").slideDown(240);
    icon.data("clicked", true);
});
```

---

**Original answer:**

Set up your elements so that icons, tooltips, and dropdowns all share a common parent.  Something like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img />
        <div>tooltip</div>
        <div>dropdown</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then, in your icon's `.click()` handler, find the tooltip and dropdown in the icon's parent:

```js
$("li > img").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find("div").show();
});
```

Alternatively, do it by index.  Set up your icons in the same order in the markup as their respective tooltips and dropdowns:

```html
<div class="icons">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
<div class="tooltips">
    <div>tooltip</div>
    <div>tooltip</div>
    <div>tooltip</div>
</div>
<div class="dropdowns">
    <div>dropdown</div>
    <div>dropdown</div>
    <div>dropdown</div>
</div>
```

Then use `.index()` and `.eq()` to find the tooltips and dropdowns:

```js
$(".icons > img").click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $(".tooltips > div").eq(idx).show();
    $(".dropdowns > div").eq(idx).show();
});
```