# I'm struggling to get .children() to work

Tags: jquery, html, class, children

I have a bunch of items with the same class that when selected open a tooltip and dropdown menu. It works with a single item, but in order to get each one to work with it's specific child, I've used .children(). It seems to work in some places but not in others. I've narrowed down what's not working, but have zero idea as to why... please help.

HTML:

```
<div class="topIcon">

<a href="stream.html"><img src="icons/stream16lg.png" /></a>
<div class="topIconNew"></div>
<div class="topTip">
    <div class="topTipText">Stream</div>
</div>
<div class="topDrop">Hello</div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("div.topIconNew").click(function(){
 //working
$(this).parent("div.topIcon, div#topSend, div#topTool").css("background-color","#555555");
 //working
$(this).children("div.topTip").show();  
 //not working
$(this).children("div.topTip").animate({width:320,marginLeft:-240},"fast");
 //not working
$(this).children("div.topDrop").slideDown(240);
clicked = true;
});
```

I haven't included the CSS because I'm not sure it's really what the issue is here. I'm thinking it's my jQuery, but I don't know really.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: +1 for the awesome title

Comment: "I'm struggling to get .children() to work." Hey, there's a reason child labor laws exist.

Comment: This is duplicate to the [previous question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425104/why-wont-this-children-work-for-me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'm a little confused about the JavaScript you have. For example, `div.topIconNew` has no children, so Im not sure why your `$(this).children("div.topTip").show();` should work? Maybe you want to use `$(this).siblings("div.topTip").show();`?

Heres the JavaScript that would work for you:

```
$("div.topIconNew").click(function(){
    $(this).parent("div.topIcon, div#topSend, div#topTool")
           .css("background-color","#555555");

    $(this).siblings("div.topTip")
           .show()
           .animate({width:320,marginLeft:-240},"fast");

    $(this).siblings("div.topDrop").slideDown(240);

    clicked = true;
});
```

Comment: Aha! I feel stupid. I appreciate that comment because that's exactly it (I hope). They are siblings, not children. But then why in the hell does it work when I have .children().show()? Weird. I'll try it with siblings though and hopefully that works. I can't believe I missed that... especially considering how long I've stared at the damn code.

Comment: And it works! Although I still need to figure out the best way to get the damn dropdown to go away when I click outside... but at least I made one step in the right direction. THANK YOU!

Comment: maybe double check your closing tags? it could be that you incorrectly nested some HTML somewhere? just guessing at this point as to why it would work intermittently

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
<div class="topIconNew"></div>
<div class="topTip">
    <div class="topTipText">Stream</div>
</div>
<div class="topDrop">Hello</div>
```

should be

```
<div class="topIconNew">
    <div class="topTip">
        <div class="topTipText">Stream</div>
    </div>
    <div class="topDrop">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `topTip` is not a child or any descendant of `topIconNew`. It is a sibling. So you want to use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

```
$("div.topIconNew").click(function() {
    $(this).parent("div.topIcon, div#topSend, div#topTool").css("background-color","#555555");
    $(this).siblings("div.topTip").show();  
    $(this).siblings("div.topTip").animate({width:320,marginLeft:-240},"fast");
    $(this).siblings("div.topDrop").slideDown(240);
    clicked = true;
});
```